# Как проверить что пользователь запретил использовать данные о геолокации?

Tags: javascript, геолокация

```
  const getUserLocation = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let currentPosition = null;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        currentPosition = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude,
        };
        resolve(currentPosition);
      });
    } else {
      reject('error');
    }
  });
};
```

Вот такой код попадает в `else`, если браузер не поддерживает `navigator.geolocation`. Но как узнать, что браузер поддерживает, но в push окне пользователь нажал "запретить" предоставлять данные геолокации?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147997/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(position){
    //действия с полученными данными
  }, function(error){
    // если ошибка (можно проверить код ошибки)
    if(error.PERMISSION_DENIED){
      alert("you denied me!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Можете попробовать так (как пример)։

```
 if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log("Geolocation not supported by your browser");

     } else {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
                console.log("i'm tracking you!");
            },
            function (error) {
                if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    console.log("Denied");
            });
     }
```

Comment: это мне не подходит. Это как раз тот случай, когда браузер вообще не поддерживает геолокацию. Но он поддерживает, просто пользователь запретил ей пользоваться.

Comment: @РоманТатаринов В этом ответе делается сначала проверка на поддержку, а потом - на запрет

Comment: @РоманТатаринов - если честно не понял ваше замечание )) на то и я поставил IF. если не поддерживается, то в консоли напишет Geolocation not supported by your browser, если поддерживает, перейдёт дальше и проверит разрешил ли пользователь или нет )) вы хоть проверили мой код до того как комментировать ?

Comment: @РоманТатаринов ответ тоже правильный, [watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) - *callback функция, которая будет вызывается при любом обновлении данных о местоположении*. Чтобы проверить просто поставьте `alert` вместо `console.log`(так нагляднее)

Comment: @Arsen, да, сорри. Просто я проглядел сначала. У вас правильный ответ

Comment: @РоманТатаринов Вы можете галку с моего ответа снять(нажмите на нее) и поставить этому, так как этот ответ и правильный и первый.

Comment: @РоманТатаринов  не надо менять галку ))